# D3.js animation for donut labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I already have a donut chart in d3.js.

The animation for the labels is some thing like this right now :

***starting point of labels*** : the labels are all in the center of the donut

***ending point*** : they end up going behind the arcs.

Now below is what i am trying to achieve....

**what i want to achieve :**

I want to change the starting point of labels.

I want the labels to appear from **behind the arcs** of the donuts instead of 
the center.

The ending point is fine like it is now.

Is there a way i can achieve this ?

i.e change the emission point of the labels instead from the center they should
appear from behind the arcs.

Here is the code that i am trying to modify :

```
 var text=svg.selectAll('text')
  .data(pie(dataset.data))
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
.attr("transform", function (d) {
    console.log(d);
    console.log(arc.centroid(d));
     var c = arc.centroid(d),
            x = c[0],
            y = c[1],
            h = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);
   return "translate(" + (x/h * labelr) +  ',' +
           (y/h * labelr) +  ")";
  })
  .attr("dy", ".4em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d){
      return d.data +"%";
  })
  .style({
      fill:'#000',
      'font-size':'11px'
  });
```

Below is the link to the fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/ahc4wdjk/

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/zrahm2h4/1/

Comment: Perfect !!! Awesome...!!! 
how did you do that  ? what part of code did you modified ?

Comment: I wrote an answer explaining.

Comment: @simon, if Gerardo answered your question, don't forget to accept it, by clicking the check mark

Answer (score 1):

In D3 [transition](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Transitions.md) selections, the starting value is the current atribute value. So, we start creating the texts behind the arcs:

```
.attr("x", function(d){
   return arc.centroid(d)[0]
})
.attr("y", function(d){
   return arc.centroid(d)[1]
})
```

I had a problem here, because your arcs don't show up at the same time. The solution was giving the texts an initial `.attr("opacity", 0)` and waiting a little bit (using `delay(1000)`).

Then, I used your code for the final position, but changing `labelr` to `labelr = radius - 160;`.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/zrahm2h4/1/